# HDInsight vs. Virtualized Hadoop Cluster on Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm investigating two alternatives for using a Hadoop cluster, the first one is using HDInsight (with either Blob or HDFS storage) and the second alternative is deploying a powerful Windows Server on Microsoft Azure and run HDP (Hortonwork Data Processing) on it (using virtualization). The second alternative gives me more flexibility, however what I'm interested in is investigating the overhead of each alternative. Any ideas on that? Particularly how is the effect of Blob storage in the efficiency?

Comment: I haven't tried either options so this is just a comment instead of an answer. That said, just based on the fact that HDInsight is a targeted service, I would be surprised if it weren't a much more cost-effective option.

Comment: what is really important to me is the performance, not cost!

Comment: In that case, measure measure measure!

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty broad question, so an answer of "it depends," is appropriate here.  When I talk with customers, this is how I see them making the tradeoff.  It's a spectrum of control at one end, and convenience on the other. Do you have specific requirements on which Linux distro or Hadoop distro you deploy?  Then you will want to go with IaaS and simply deploy there.  That's great, you get a lot of control, but patching and operations are still your responsibility.

We refer to HDInsight as a managed service, and what we mean by that is that we take care of running it for you (eg, there is an SLA we provide on the cluster itself, and the apps running on it, not just "can I ping the vm").  We operate that cluster, patch the OS, patch Hadoop, etc.  So, lots of convenience there, but, we don't let you choose which Linux distro or allow you to have an arbitrary set of Hadoop bits there.

From a perf perspective, HDInsight can deploy on any Azure node size, similar to IaaS VM's (this is a new feature launched this week).  On the question of Blob efficiency, you should try both out and see what you think.  The nice part about Blob store is you get more economic flexibility, you can deploy a small cluster on a massive volume of data if that cluster only needs to run on a small chunk of data (as compared to putting it all in HDFS, where you need all of the nodes running all of the time to fit all of your data).